# ViewModel behind the scene

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-jetpack, android-architecture-components

I don't understand How does the ViewModel instance created be alive when the UI controller recreated ?

In other words...
whey this method

```
ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

return the previous exiting ViewModel instance when re-invoked?

Comment: ViewModel is fragment without UI and with setRetainInstance(true), who is attached, scoped to the passed fragment or Activity, so when the activity will be recreated for rotation for example it will be saved, and the call will return the same instance, the basic rule, if ViewModel exist on the same scope, the same instance will be returned otherwise a new instance will be created.

Comment: Thanks Anis, But are you sure ViewModel is a fragment ??
ViewModel class doesn't extend the fragment

Answer (score 0):

**get(MyViewModel.class)**

Returns an existing ViewModel or creates a new one in the scope (usually, a fragment or an activity), associated with this.The created ViewModel is associated with the given scope and will be retained
     as long as the scope is alive (e.g. if it is an activity, until it is
     finished or process is killed)

```
public <T extends ViewModel> T get(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
    String canonicalName = modelClass.getCanonicalName();
    if (canonicalName == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Local and anonymous classes can not be ViewModels");
    }
    return get(DEFAULT_KEY + ":" + canonicalName, modelClass);
}
```

if we further explore, the **get(String key,  Class modelClass)** method with two parameters return view model. You can see in the function if the view model exist it will return otherwise it will create a new one.

```
public <T extends ViewModel> T get(@NonNull String key, @NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
        ViewModel viewModel = mViewModelStore.get(key);

        if (modelClass.isInstance(viewModel)) {
            //noinspection unchecked
            return (T) viewModel;
        } else {
            //noinspection StatementWithEmptyBody
            if (viewModel != null) {
                // TODO: log a warning.
            }
        }

        viewModel = mFactory.create(modelClass);
        mViewModelStore.put(key, viewModel);
        //noinspection unchecked
        return (T) viewModel;
    }
```

[Here is the reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider)

Comment: Thanks  Mushahid, it helped me alot

Answer (score 0):

After a  good search I found this [post](https://android.jlelse.eu/deep-dive-inside-of-androids-viewmodel-architecture-components-e6756dc0bb11) which explains what I need exactly..

Comment: I think it is not valid any more. I can see in code that `ViewModelStore` is restored with `getLastNonConfigurationInstance`, not with `setRetainInstance` in `Fragment`